# Using templated function without template parameter

Tags: c++, function, templates

I'm using the following code to load objects (A, B and C which are subclasses of Object) from file. The compilation issue I have is from loadObjFromLine

```
load.h:611:33: erreur: there are no arguments to ‘loadObjFromLine’ that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of ‘loadObjFromLine’ must be available [-fpermissive]
load.h:611:33: note: (if you use ‘-fpermissive’, G++ will accept your code, but allowing the use of an undeclared name is deprecated)
```

And when I use `pObj = loadObjFromLine<T>(line);` , I get

```
load.h: In function ‘bool loadObjects(const string&, Object<T>*&)’:
load.h:611:13: erreur: ‘loadObjFromLine’ was not declared in this scope
load.h:611:30: erreur: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
```

**EDIT**
I know I could use `loadObjFromLine<double>` but I'd like the type T to be the same used in loadObject(Object*&). Maybe it's not the right approach..

Any idea ?

```
template<typename T>
Object<T>* loadObjFromLine(const std::string& line)
{
    std::stringstream lineStream(line);
    int objType(-1);
    lineStream >> objType;

    Object<T> *pObj = NULL;

    if (objType == 0)
    {
        A<T> *pO = new A<T>;
        if (lineStream >> *pO)
            pObj = pO;
    }
    else if (objType == 1)
    {
        B<T> *pO = new B<T>;
        if (lineStream >> *pO)
            pObj = pO;
    }
    else if (objType == 2)
    {
        C<T> *pO = new C<T>;
        if (lineStream >> *pO)
            pObj = pO;
    }

    return pObj;
}

template <typename T>
bool loadObjects(   const std::string &filename, Object<T>*& pObj)
{
    std::ifstream fileStream(filename.c_str());
    if (fileStream.good())
    {
        std::string line;
        int objType;

        // Loading boundary.
        while(std::getline(fileStream, line))
        {
            pObj = loadObjFromLine(line);
//          pObj = loadObjFromLine<T>(line);
            if (!pObj)
                return false;
        }
        fileStream.close();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: what's wrong with `pObj = loadObjFromLine<T>(line);`? It's clean and clear. The solution provided in German's answer cannot be recommended (see comment).

Comment: @Walter, as stated in my post, it doesn't compile. Maybe I missed something, but what ?

Comment: @Walter, ok, it works if I put loadObjFromLine() before loadObject() ... It's in order here, it wasn't in my code ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this:

```
LoadObjFromLine<Type>(line);
```

As you can see, there is a string parameter and a template parameter:

```
template <class T>
Obj<T> * LoadObjFromLine(std::string const & line);
```

You cannot deduce the parameter. In order for the parameter to be deduced, the signature should be something like this (note I change the return type to `void` also).

```
template <class Obj>
void LoadObjFromLine(std::string const & line, Obj * obj);
```

This way you could do something like:

```
Obj<MyType> * obj;
LoadObjFromLine(line, obj);
```

And obj would be deduced.

In  your case there is no argument to pass to function in order to deduce `T` template parameter.

EDIT: As commented below, the preferred signature for `LoadObjFromLine` would be the one used in your program, and not the one using `void` as the return type. *The example with void signature was just for the purpose of illustrating when a template parameter can be deduced vs when a template parameter cannot be deduced*.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think of it .. Thanks.

Comment: passing the pointer `Obj*pObj` as parameter just so that the type can be deduced is a **bad motivation**. The clean way is to return the pointer as in the original code (and give the type as `<T>`), since then it's obvious from that the pointer `pObj` is assigned.

Comment: This was only for the purpose of illustration to make clear why the parameter cannot be deduced. I find this signature comparison illustrative of why one can be deduced and the other version cannot. I agree the best way is to give the template parameter explicitely.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the type loadObjFromLine should be instantiated with explicitly, for example: `loadObjFromLine<T>("hgjghgj")`.

The compiler's error message is quite useful in this case: the compiler cannot deduce the type it should instantiate your function with (as it doesn't depend on function's parameters), so you need to be explicit about it.